# How was the critical exponents related to the scaling dimensions of the local operators?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, critical-phenomena

On "The Conformal Bootstrap: Theory, Numerical Techniques, and Applications"(arXiv:1805.04405
) by David Poland, Slava Rychkov, Alessandro Vichi page 5

> Consider for example the critical exponents. In RG theory they can be related to the
> eigenvalues $\lambda^{y_i}$ of the RG transformation linearized around the fixed point, where λ > 1 is the RG rescaling factor. As is well known, these eigenvalues are simply related to the scaling dimensions of the local operators: $y_i = d − \Delta_i$

In "Applied Conformal Field Theory" by Paul Ginsparg page 60 and 61 also talked about the critical exponent.

$\langle \sigma_n \sigma_0\rangle \sim \frac{1}{|n|^{d-2+\eta}}$
and $\langle \sigma_n\sigma_{n+1}\sigma_0\sigma_1\rangle\sim\frac{1}{|n|^{2(d-1/\nu)}}$, where $\eta$ and $\nu$ were the exponent, and on page 61 the paper mentioned the actual critical exponent from the thermal dynamics (I suppose those were the actual $\lambda^{y_i}$ of the RG flow) of the specific heat $C\sim t^{-\alpha}$.

Clearly, the relations between the $\lambda^{y_i}$ and the scaling dimensions are more complicated than just $y_i=d-\Delta_i$, and on the [Wikipedia's Ising critical exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_critical_exponents), the "general expression" of different exponents were rather complicated, and different from each other.

Further, Paul Ginsparg page 61 also mentioned the connection that

> according to the scaling hypothesis, the divergence of all thermodynamic quantities at the critical point is due to their dependence on the correlation length $\xi$

I'm a bit lost at that point, since the CFT is a scaling invariant theory, and the the correlation length or $\langle \epsilon(r)\epsilon(0)\rangle = \frac{1}{r^p} g(r/\xi)$ did not make any sense. For any local operators, the $r$ could just be pushed around withe the conformal invariance, and I thought that the $r$ could only be made comparable to $\xi$ in some special types of lattice model.

How was the critical exponents related to the scaling dimensions of the local operators? Do they have a general form? Does the scaling dimension of the local operators necessarily related to a thermodynamic critical quantity?